# get value from a textbox in HTML part of Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm totally new to JSP and servlet so this question might be really unusual or easy to solve!
i'm trying to get the value of the `id=creditcard` and `id=expirationDate` input fields! in a function in servelet to check whether the fields matches the data in database as follow:

**HTML within servlet:**

```
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Make payment</title>");
    out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>");
    out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/payment.js'></script>");
    out.println("<link type='text/css' href='css/style.css' rel='Stylesheet' />");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<div class='bg-light' style='width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left:50%; top:50%;  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 10px;'>");
    out.println("<input id='reservationID' style='display: none' value='"+rb.reservationID+"' />");
    out.println("<div>Credit Card Number : </div>");
    out.println("<div><input id='creditcard' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' type='text' name='creditcard' maxlength='16' /></div>");
    out.println("<div>ExpirationDate : </div>");
    out.println("<div><input id='expirationDate' type='text' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' name='expirationDate' maxlength='4' /></div>");
    out.println("<span style='font-size: 75%;'>"+Error+"</span>");
    out.println("<div><input type='button'  name='buttonsave' value='Make Payment' onclick='makePayment("+rb.reservationID+");' /></div>");
    out.println("<div><input type='button'  name='buttoncancel' value='Cancel Payment' onclick='cancelPayment("+rb.reservationID+");' /></div>");
    out.println("</div>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
```

and i'm using a function in servlet to check the input and display error in `out.println("<span style='font-size: 75%;'>"+Error+"</span>")` if its wrong.

**servlet function:**

```
String Error= "";
bolean check = us.checkCC(userID, creditno, expiration); // i need the values here!
....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get those values in your Servlet like `request.getParameter("creditcard");` and `request.getParameter("expirationDate");`. P.S : Those input fields require the name attributes `creditcard` and `expirationDate`. The `id` attribute is referred to by JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using AJAX as you're using the type of the buttons, `button` - `type="button"`? Otherwise, the type should be submit.

Comment: yes I'm using Ajax Post method in the `payment.js`

Answer (score 1):

> boolean check = us.checkCC(userID, creditno, expiration); // i need
>   the values here!

You can get the values, by extracting those from `request` object being passed to the appropriate method.

If you're submitting the form by `post` then the doPost code within a servlet shall look something like this :

```
public class NewClass extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String creditno = req.getParameter("creditcard");       //name of the input field, not id
        String expiration = req.getParameter("expirationDate");     //name of the input field should be expirationDate
        //...  Other code follows here
    }
}
```

Comment: you mentioned, that you're using ajax post.

Comment: I meant, i haven't used any `<form>`. and yes i used ajax post in my java script file. I added the code as you suggested to `doPost`! if I want to use these values to check them against date in database, where should I add the `bolean check = us.checkCC(userID, creditno, expiration);`? inside the doPost or use global variables for `creditno` and `expiration`?

Comment: inside doPost of course. `Other code follows here` - write your code here.

Comment: Thank you very much! that helped a lot ! I was wondering is there a way to access `bolean check` value in javascript? I've tried `sessionattribute`m but it seems that it's not possible to access it directly from JS. is there a way to add a hidden attribute to DOM in doPOST ? Thanks again!

Comment: because it's out of the scope of the question i created another question! [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887753/how-to-add-hidden-attribute-to-dom-using-servlet)