# how to add hidden attribute to DOM using Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

How can i set hiddent attribute in dom using servlet doPost! the HTML is created by servlet as follow:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("<title>Make payment</title>");
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>");
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/payment.js'></script>");
out.println("<link type='text/css' href='css/style.css' rel='Stylesheet' />");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
out.println("<div class='bg-light' style='width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left:50%; top:50%;  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 10px;'>");
out.println("<input id='reservationID' style='display: none' value='"+rb.reservationID+"' />");
out.println("<div>Credit Card Number : </div>");
out.println("<div><input id='creditcard' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' type='text' name='creditcard' maxlength='16' /></div>");
out.println("<div>ExpirationDate : </div>");
out.println("<div><input id='expirationDate' type='text' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' name='expirationDate' maxlength='4' /></div>");
out.println("<span style='font-size: 75%;'>"+Error+"</span>");
out.println("<div><input type='button'  name='buttonsave' value='Make Payment' onclick='makePayment("+rb.reservationID+");' /></div>");
out.println("<div><input type='button'  name='buttoncancel' value='Cancel Payment' onclick='cancelPayment("+rb.reservationID+");' /></div>");
out.println("</div>");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

HTTP servlet Reqest to get values of `creditcard` and `expirationDate` fields. using them I'm comparing the fields value to the database and set CCA

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    creditno = request.getParameter("creditcard");       //name of the input field, not id
    expiration = request.getParameter("expirationDate");     //name of the input field should be expirationDate

    if (request.getParameter("buttonsave") != null) {
        UserBean us = new UserBean();
        boolean check = us.checkCC(userID, request.getParameter("creditcard"), request.getParameter("expirationDate"));
        if (check == true) {
            CCA = 1;
        } else {
            CCA = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to access these variables from Javascript in payment.js to give alert! how can i read this in javascript? writing it to a hidden field in DOM ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you put this value into the `DOM` and rely on it then the user can (very easily) change it. The best way may be to do this via Ajax.

Comment: show your ajax post request code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something similar,

```
 out.println("<input type='hidden' id='FormName' name='FormName' value='"+HiddenValue+"'>");
```

In `doPost` method,

```
FormName = request.getParameter("FormName");
```

Comment: Well my question is how to add value to this from `doPost`! should I add this to my HTML part and then insert the value from `doPost` if so how can i do it ?

Comment: isn't `FormName = request.getParameter("FormName");` get's parametet from the attribute instead of setting it ? and by `FormName` do you mean it need to be similar to form's name ?

Comment: FormName, I meant your desired input element name.